# Es posible implementar codigo o funciones javascript en un archivo de React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, responsive, menu

Por favor, estoy tratando de darme una idea o como podría implementar código javascript para hacer la funcionalidad de un menú desplegable, cuando le pongo   me sale error con ese código de javascript

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const Body = () => {

    

    return ( 
        
       <main>

            <div className="topnav">
            <a className="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">Research Institute Projects</a>
            <a href="#contact">Press</a>
            <a href="#about">Volunter</a>
            <a href="#about">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">Donate</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
             </a>
            </div>
          

        <section className="container-fluid" >
            <img className="ImageNSV" alt="NSV" width={"160px"} src={window.location.origin + '/img/icon.png'}  />
        </section>

        <section className="main_container">
            <div>
                <h1>Research Institute Projects</h1>
            </div>

              <div className="odd" >
                    <ul className="first">
                        <li><h5>Project</h5></li>
                        <li><p>Designed for parents,teachers and school counselors</p></li>
                        <li><button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Open Tool</button></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul className="second">
                        <li>
                            <p>Have you seen behavioural changes in your child or student and want
                            to know which type of violence those behaviors might trigger?</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>


        </section>
      </main>
     );
}
 
export default Body;
```

Ahora quiero colocar esta funcion de javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Todo codigo es escrito, [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/432337/edit) tu pregunta y agregalo

Comment: listo ya agrege el código , gracias

Comment: @GabrielQuezadaCastro, veo que estas teniendo problemas para implementar la solución propuesta ¿Lograste avanzar? Saludos

Comment: aun no g.4 estoy presentando dificultades

Answer (score 0):

Hola Gabriel buenas tardes, recuerda que react es un lenguaje javascript entonces no necesitas definir el tab de script la funcion puede quedar de esta manera

```
myFunction = (params) => {
   ....introducir el código aquí
}
```

y puedes hacer el llamado desde cualquier lugar del código de llamando **myFuncion**.

si quieres obtener la referencia de un objeto creado en react puedes usar este hook useRef te dejo por aquí la documentación.
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

en cuanto a lo que estas tratando de hacer que creo que es asignar o una stilo como tal a un control en al interfaz, veo que tienes un div lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente.

antes del return defines una variable const que va a tener lo que necesitas o let dependiendo del comportamiento que necesitas, por ejemplo aqui changeClass recibe el comportamiento true o false de **cualquierFuncionQueNecesites()** y segun eso asigna una estilo al div..

```
const changeClass = cualquierFuncionQueNecesites()

return(
   <div id={'myTopnav'} className={ changeClass ? 'topnav' : 'responsive' }>
   ....
)
```

Comment: en que parte exactamente tengo que colocar la funcion , es que lo hice y me salio error , lo puse antes del const body = () => { y me salio que la funcion no es definida  y si lo pongo dentro del return me sale error de unexpected token

Comment: Hay que editar esta respuesta, la definición propuesta para declarar la función usa sintaxis `Class Component`, el OP esta mostrando en el ejemplo un `Funcional Component`.

Comment: a que te refieres con OP, por favor

Comment: @GabrielQuezadaCastro, se dice OP (Original Poster) a la persona que inicia la pregunta, en este caso eres tú. Voy a continuar comentando en la pregunta original.